# Read and display an image in terms of a pixel matrix - getting an error

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pixel, spyder

This is my code to read an image and display in terms of a pixel matrix

```
    PIL import Image
    import os.path

    filename = os.path.join('seaturtle.jpg')
    img = Image.open('seaturtle.jpg')
    width, height = img.size
    print ("Dimensions:", img.size, "Total pixels:", width * height)
    x = img.size #Here it is 1000,480
    y = width*height
    import cv2
    cv2.__version__
    import numpy as np
    def get_num_pixels(filepath):
        width, height = Image.open(open('seaturtle.jpg')).size
        return width*height
    img = Image.open('seaturtle.jpg')
    arr = np.array(img) # 640x480x4 array
    arr[x] # 4-vector, just like above]
    print(*arr, sep=", ")
```

But I am getting this error

```
IndexError: index 1000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 480
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: is this the whole code ? if so where do you set filepath from filename ?

Comment: what are you trying to do in this line `arr[x]` ? array indexing starts with zero, if you have 1000 rows then last index will be 999. Now, if you place x i.e. (1000,480) then it means you are trying to access 1001th row and 481th column, so there will be index out of bound